# Comparing elements at the same index

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to compare element at the same index of two lists in haskell. If the two elements are equal an at the same index then I have to return that index. 
i know how to compare two function using filter and zip, but my function return the value instead of the index.

```
 compare l1 l2 = map fst . filter (\(x,y) -> x == y) $ zip l1 l2
```

When I run it with ghci i have

```
compare [1,2,3,4,5] [1,2,3,7,8,9,11,5]
[1,2,3]
```

I want to have `[0,1,2]` instead. Can anybody give me hints how to go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `zip3` and `[0..]` to include an index as the first item of a tuple of size three:

```hs
compare l1 l2 = map (\(i, _, _) -> i) . filter (\(_, x,y) -> x == y) $ zip3 [0..] l1 l2
```

Answer (score 5):

A list comprehension makes Chad Gilbert's answer a little cleaner.

```
compare l1 l2 = [i | (i, x, y) <- zip3 [0..] l1 l2, x == y]
```

Comment: It is a matter of habit and style. I would have written `compare' xs ys = map fst . filter snd . zip [0..] $ zipWith (==) xs ys`

Answer (score 4):

Use the `findIndices` function from `Data.List`. In ghci:

```
Data.List> findIndices id $ zipWith (==) [1,2,3,4,5] [1,2,3,7,8,9,11,5]
[0,1,2]
```